# Regex: Validating triple letters with comma separation

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

Another regex question (still in the throws of learning).  I'm trying to validate user enters three letters, and only three letters, then an optional comma plus additional three letters, ad infinitum.

Hence the following would be allowed:

aaa

aaa,aaa

aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa

But the following would not:

aa

aaa,aa

aaa,aaaa

aaa,aaa,aaaa

and so on.

The regex I have for the first triplet of letters is:

```
 (^\s*)(\b[a-z]{3}\b){1}
```

and the repeating comma and triplet is:

```
 (,\b[a-z]{3}\b){0,}
```

using the {0,} so that it is optional but repeating

But as you can probably tell, it's not working when I bring things together.

Any ideas would be gratefully received

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be:

```
^([a-z]{3},)*[a-z]{3}$
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working.  The comma in between the first bracket would mean that it was mandatory so I couldn't just have aaa on its own.  Also for some reason within vba I'm needing the /b around the values to limit to just 3 characters.

Comment: this matches "aaa" on it's own just fine.

Comment: Perfect :-)   Thanks a million; works a treat.  The carat and dollar sign string match are new to me; I'll go do some more learning.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it if you wanted to catch upper and lower case and to ensure that the comma is optional.

*edit I've changed it to include a way to have a of delimiting character `[, ]` in it which is required rather than only an optional comma.

```
([a-zA-Z]{3}([, ]))*
```

Comment: This will match: `abcdefghi`